# How to keep latest file and previous latest file?

Tags: bash, shell, file-copy

I run a script in which generates a text file. Lets call it file-a.txt. Then I run same script again and will overwrite the same file-a.txt but if course with new content. Thats ok. But now I want everytime I run the script I want to keep that file-a.txt and when I run it again I want that then new “file-a.txt” its the lastest new file and “file-a.txt” now its the previous lastest file.
So I need only to have always the lastest file that its generated after I run the script and also to keep the previous one only.  I hope I explain correctly.
Example:

1. file-a. (First file generated)
   2.run script again and now file-a is the new latest but i want to keep the content of the previous file-a; etc

I tried making a copy of file-a like

- cp file-a file-a-old but tried other things unsucesful.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `cp file-a file-a-old but tried other things unsucesful` ... how was it unsuccessful?

Answer (score 2):

Let your script generate a temporary file and then use `mv -b` to overwrite the previous one. `mv` will create a backup `file-a.txt~`.

> `-b, --backup[=CONTROL]` make a backup of each existing destination file

```bsh
script_generating_tmp_file && mv -b "file-a.txt.tmp" "file-a.txt"
```

You will get:

```
$ ls -1
file-a.txt # <-- latest file
file-a.txt~ # <-- previous file
```

Comment: nice find, I didn't know `-b` trick !! (only been using `mv` for 30 years)

Comment: The `-b` is not required/defined by POSIX. GNU `mv(1)`  has it though. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html

Answer (score 1):

You could write a new script that calls your original script.
Suppose the original script is called `original-script`; let's call this one `wrapper-script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Save a copy of latest file-a.txt before generating a new one;
# but don't bother trying if file-a.txt does not exist.
if test -f file-a.txt; then
    cp -a file-a.txt file-a-old.txt
fi

original-script # Run script that generates file-a.txt here.
```

The logic is as follows:

The first time through, there should be no `file-a.txt` yet, so `file-a-old.txt` is not created. The existing script generates `file-a.txt`, but nothing generates `file-a-old.txt`.

All other times, `file-a.txt` exists, so we make a copy of it called `file-a-copy.txt`. At this point, there are 2 identical files: `file-a.txt` and `file-a-old.txt`. When `original-script` runs, it overwrites `file-a.txt`, but `file-a.old.txt` remains.

You can also add this logic to `original-script` itself, if that makes sense for your usecase. Otherwise, you can run `wrapper-script` instead of `original-script` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: How do you interpret the issue that your answer solves? It's important to know why you believe your code would work, and part of that is knowing what you think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logrotate to make two backups of your file. In that way you will have:

```
file
file.1
file.2
```

First, create a configuration file like this:

```
<path to your file> {
    rotate 2
    daily
    size 1
    notifempty
    missingok
}
```

Then you run

```
logrotate -f <path to config file>
```

`-f` means force and it ignores a setting `daily` from the config file. Daily is the shortest period, and I am ot sure if you can ommit it. `-f` makes sure it rotates even, if it would already be rotated in the last day. I think, other options (`size`, `notifempty`,...) are ignored with `-f`, too.

If you want more older copies increase the number at `rotate` option.